# unable to Understand this code. Ternary operators

Tags: java

I cannot understand this piece of code. The ternary operators are confusing me.

```
  public Collection<V> values() {
    Collection<V> vs;
    return (vs = values) == null ? (values = new Values()) : vs;
}
```

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: What is `Values`? Does it implement `Collection<V>`?

Comment: Note: This is the implementation of the `values` method on `HashMap`.

Comment: Hi Eran,This is code from the hashmap api. the part that i was not able to understand was  return (vs = values) == null ? (values = new Values()) : vs; I am not sure why you have marked mine as negative.

Comment: If you don't understand ternary operators, then do research on them.

Comment: Do you not understand ternary operators in general?  Or just this particular nasty expression?

Comment: First of all you should say what exactly you do not understand. Furthermore as @Eran already mentioned you should avoid having such magic variables if they are of interest in your question.

Comment: Tom might be you were born intelligent. I did search but i could not understand this part.

Comment: No I wasn't, but I've learned to read.

Comment: Ternary operators follow the `CONDITION(true : false) ? Statement(true) : Statement(false)` construct.

Comment: But for the record: this is terrible, ugly code. Even when you are an experienced person, you will have to read that multiple time to get its meaning. So yes, research ternary expressions; but dont be worried that you do not easily comprehend this great how-to-not-write-code example.

Comment: @marstran from OpenJDK ([link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.values%28%29)). Oracle JDK uses a normal `if`/`else` block.

Comment: Thanks Dennis! I get this now.

Comment: @GhostCat not that unreadable, I found this quite well organize to get a short version of a simple code. Still not sure why the need for `vs` here, it adds a bit more complexity but I prefer this version (as a ternary operator lover ;) ) compared to the accepted answer

Comment: @AxelH It violates the single responsibility principle; with that re-assigning to values. And anything that forces me to read it more than 2 times is ghostcat-unreadable. You see: the method name *implies* this thing just returns "values"; but it actually does "init" fields as well. Wouldnt pass a code review in my team ;-) In that sense: the accepted answer makes it easier to understand what the code is doing; but I would still rewrite this code and do it differently overall.

Comment: @GhostCat Actually, it is not `getValues()` so the return of a non-null value is probably documented but not provided. As the review, I would refuse both ... as neither are reduce the complexity to the minimum.

Comment: @Tom That's right. I forgot to specify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to:

```
public Collection<V> values() {
    Collection<V> vs = values;
    if (vs == null) {
        values = new Values();
        return values;
    } else {
        return vs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Equivalent in functionality, but not in readability.  Yours is _much_ clearer!

Comment: What is 'values' from line 2? Where does it come from? Is it a 'pointer' to the method name?

Comment: @M.Schwarzer-Haverbier `values` is a field, a field in the `HashMap` class to be exact.

Comment: Thanks kejn that was nice of you!

Comment: @KevinAnderson to be honest, if I was to write this code it would be:

    `public Collection<V> values() {
        if (values == null) {
            values = new Values();
        }
        return values;
    }`